# Caffeine Cache - how does the expireAfterWrite() parameter works?

Tags: caffeine-cache

I would like to understand, how expired entries are removed when using the Caffeine Cache with the expireAfterWrite() parameter. Is the removal done upon calling the getIfPresent() and/or .size() method?

If yes, how can we make sure we dont run into issues when there many inserts but a few get() calls against the cache? I would like not to have to call the size() method in a scheduled method.

Comment: Please review the [docs](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Cleanup) and let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thanks a lot, missed that part in the docs